# CakePHP: Max number of associations?

Tags: cakephp, associations

With a hasMany, HABTM, or doing the hasMany through thing, is there a clean way of making sure that a certain type of association has a cap? Say, one Post can only have 3 Tags?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be beforeSave callback to calculate the number of associated rows, if its >= 3 return false. A counterCache could help with performance.

Comment: beforeSave would work just fine. From what I can tell, limit just adds a limit to the MYSQL query. I didn't think it would let me set a maximum amount of possible associations.

Comment: You're right. I misread the docs. Thought that wasn't the correct behavior initially too heh